# How could I pivot quarterly data from a table in a view and make it updateable somehow?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I currently have a table that stores information on a quarterly basis in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[payroll](
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [fk_employer] [bigint] NULL,
    [branch] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [natural_year] [int] NULL,
    [fiscal_year] [int] NULL,
    [quarter] [varchar](2) NULL,
    [payroll_total] [bigint] NULL,
    [emp_total] [bigint] NULL,
    [tax_total] [bigint] NULL,
    [created_on] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [created_by] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [updated_on] [datetime] NULL,
    [updated_by] [varchar](50) NULL
```

And I would like to display this information in a year by year basis with `payroll_total` for all 4 quarters, `emp_total` for all 4 quarters, and `tax_total` for all 4 quarters. So for example the result would be something like:

`[fk_employer], [branch], [natural_year], [payroll_total_Q1], [payroll_total_Q2], [payroll_total_Q3], [payroll_total_Q4], [emp_total_Q1], [emp_total_Q2], [emp_total_Q3], [emp_total_Q4], [tax_total_Q1], [tax_total_Q2], [tax_total_Q3], [tax_total_Q4]`

preferably also creating another view for fiscal year (in our case Q3, Q4 then Q1, Q2 should be the same fiscal year).

Would also like it to be updateable, I know that's a stretch but I hope there's a way.

I'm not a dba so my knowledge is limited, is there a way to do this in a view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation like below

```
select 
   [fk_employer], [branch], [natural_year], 
   [payroll_total_Q1]= SUM(CASE WHEN [quarter]='Q1' THEN [payroll_total] END), 
   [payroll_total_Q2]= SUM(CASE WHEN [quarter]='Q2' THEN [payroll_total] END), 
   [payroll_total_Q3]= SUM(CASE WHEN [quarter]='Q3' THEN [payroll_total] END),  
[payroll_total_Q4]= SUM(CASE WHEN [quarter]='Q4' THEN [payroll_total] END),  
[emp_total_Q1]= SUM(CASE WHEN [quarter]='Q1' THEN [emp_total] END), 
[emp_total_Q2]= SUM(CASE WHEN [quarter]='Q2' THEN [emp_total] END), 
[emp_total_Q3]= SUM(CASE WHEN [quarter]='Q3' THEN [emp_total] END), 
[emp_total_Q4]= SUM(CASE WHEN [quarter]='Q4' THEN [emp_total] END), 
[tax_total_Q1]= SUM(CASE WHEN [quarter]='Q1' THEN [tax_total] END), 
[tax_total_Q2]= SUM(CASE WHEN [quarter]='Q2' THEN [tax_total] END), 
[tax_total_Q3]= SUM(CASE WHEN [quarter]='Q3' THEN [tax_total] END), 
[tax_total_Q4]= SUM(CASE WHEN [quarter]='Q4' THEN [tax_total] END)
from payroll
group by     
[fk_employer], [branch], [natural_year]
```

For fiscal year, just group by `fiscal_year` instead of `natural_year`, replace the select `natural_year` with `fiscal_year`